# Return value to main controller after aplying a filter?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I called a filter from my main controller like this

```
apples = $filter('toTitleCase')(pears);
```

Everything is in order, meaning there are no dependencies left to cover and everything is declared.

Then, I can also access my filter from the outside in a file called filter.js.

```
app.filter( 'toTitleCase', function(){
  return function(x){
    x.replace(/\w\S*/g, function(txt) {
      return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();
    });
  }
});
```

What it does is, it takes some input text and prints the first letters as upper case.

The problem is, when the main controller accesses filter.js, it takes the right input and , with console log, I was able to see that it did indeed make the first letters uppercase. But when the filter.js file returns the value, it comes as undefined.

Any clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem:**

The problem with your actual filter code, is that it's just processing the string and not returning it, you need to make your `filter` callback return the processed string.

This is how should be your code:

```
app.filter('toTitleCase', function() {
  return function(x) {
    return x.replace(/\w\S*/g, function(txt) {
      return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();
    });
  }
});
```

**Explanation:**

You were returning a function, that only process a string and `uppercase` its first character but doesn't return it back, you need a `return` statement in this function.

Comment: That's it! Thanks for explaining :)